# How to write a P4 program for EasyRoute protocol?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to implement an Easyroute protocol asked on https://github.com/p4lang/tutorials/tree/master/SIGCOMM_2015#obtaining-required-software. There is skeleton program given on this above github repo. But as I am new learner of P4 language, I need help to write this skeleton program given on above github repository.

Anyone who has already written and implemented above assignment can help me by posting the required P4 program.

**The skeleton program is given as**:

```
 /*
Copyright 2013-present Barefoot Networks, Inc. 

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

// TODO: define headers & header instances

parser start {
    // TODO
    return ingress;
}

// TODO: define parser states

action _drop() {
    drop();
}

action route() {
    modify_field(standard_metadata.egress_spec, /* TODO: port field from your header */);
    // TODO: update your header
}

control ingress {
    // TODO
}

control egress {
    // leave empty
}
```

Comment: Folks from Barefoot networks, Princeton University, Bradford University and any enthusiastic P4 programmer are hoped to answer this question..

Comment: Why on earth someone should spend time on your assignment? Show us some efforts. Otherwise hire someone to do the job...

Comment: LoL....[take a look at on-topic page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). SO is not a training/teaching website..

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a we do your homework for you service. Try something yourself and if you have a specific problem, you can ask about it.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 0):

### **Mininet environmeent can be created using 3 switches and 3 hosts to test.**

```
//this code is available to use under Apache License on github
    header_type easyroute_head_t {
        fields {
            preamble: 64;
                //preambe is always set to zero, that is used 
                //to identify easyrout packets from other packets.
            num_valid: 32;
    //indicates the number of valid ports in header
        }
    }
    header easyroute_head_t easyroute_head;
    header_type easyroute_port_t
     {
        fields {
            port: 8;
        }
    }
    header easyroute_port_t easyroute_port;
    parser start
     {
        return select(current(0, 64))
           //call to current is used to examine the 1st 64 bits
     {
            0: parse_head;
            default: ingress;
        }
    }
    parser parse_head 
    {
        extract(easyroute_head);
        return select(latest.num_valid)
     {
            0: ingress;
            default: parse_port;
        }

    }

    parser parse_port {
        extract(easyroute_port);
        return ingress;
    }
    action _drop()
     {
        drop();
    }
    action route()
     {
        modify_field(standard_metadata.egress_spec, easyroute_port.port);
        add_to_field(easyroute_head.num_valid, -1);
        remove_header(easyroute_port);
                //update header, call to remove header for removing header
    }
    table route_pkt
     {
        reads
     {
            easyroute_port: valid;
        }
        actions
     {
            _drop;
            route;
        }
        size: 1;
    }
    control ingress 
    {
        apply(route_pkt);
          //route_pkt is the table
    }
    control egress
     {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Place yourself in source *routing_directory.* ./run_demo.sh will compile your code and create the Mininet network described above. It will also use commands.txt to configure each one of the switches. Once the network is up and running, you should type the following in the Mininet CLI:

xterm h1
xterm h3
This will open a terminal for you on h1 and h3.

On h3 run: ./receive.py.

On h1 run: ./send.py h1 h3.

You should then be able to type messages on h1 and receive them on h3. The send.py program finds the shortest path between h1 and h3 using Dijkstra, then send correctly-formatted packets to h3 through s1 and s3][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCBmS.png)

[.pcap files will be generated for every interface (9 files: 3 for each of the 3 switches). You can look at the appropriate files and check that your packets are being processed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85EwU.png)

Answer (score 0):

The code given at  https://github.com/p4lang/tutorials/tree/master/SIGCOMM_2015#obtaining-required-software has the 'port' argument missing from the action route() method. The correct code is given below. Simply make this small change in the p4 code file and then execute the steps as mentioned in the tutorial given at https://github.com/p4lang/tutorials/tree/master/SIGCOMM_2015#obtaining-required-software.

```
 /*
Copyright 2013-present Barefoot Networks, Inc. 

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

// TODO: define headers & header instances

parser start {
    // TODO
    return ingress;
}

// TODO: define parser states

action _drop() {
    drop();
}

action route(port) {
    modify_field(standard_metadata.egress_spec, port);
    // TODO: update your header
}

control ingress {
    // TODO
}

control egress {
    // leave empty
}
```

All the Best

Comment: Rather than adding URL and saying "code given at" please add the code here in your question itself.